# step into and step over button in java eclipse disable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debugging

i am new to java and eclipse. I am facing problem in debug mode. When I run my program in debug, it run successfully. But step into, step over buttons appear disable. Due to this issue I am not able to debug my program.

thanks

Comment: That's because when program flow is halted, event-driven programming may not function. You need to use breakpoints.

Comment: just click on run and then you'll find Something like Skip all break Points.
please uncheck Skip all BreakPoints.
then Start your Debug by adding break point.
It will work fine for eclipse user.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when stepping through the program, you halt the Swing event thread, and this inactivates the GUI. You need to use breakpoints in your event listeners, and then inside of these listeners, step through your code after the break-point has been reached.

Note: I'm assuming that you're trying to debug a Swing GUI. Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a noob programmer, just beginning to get my toes wet. I have wasted an entire day trying to search and think what was wrong. After reading what Hovercraft Full Of Eels had to say, I finally got my answer.

Such a dumb thing to do (given my loooooong experience of programming - 15 yrs).

I had placed all my breakpoints on non executable statements, i.e. variable declarations. Be sure to put your breakpoints in one of the methods that will execute during your debug session and only then you will be able to see active Step into, Step over buttons.

Answer (score 0):

When you run some project with dependencies to other libraries or projects and you create a breakpoint, its possible that referencies didn't have created to the debug indexing.

The best option is stop the server and re-run it with the breakpoints created in those classes referenced out of your main project. It works for me.